# advanced conditional regex with multi capturing and lookarounds

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

At work I need a regex to match different kinds of products in a huge old catalogue that was imported on digital support in a really bad way (lots of errors, different styles, etc). While matching, I have to capture the product's type and its diameter (the value inside the parenthesis). Finally, I have to discard bad formatted entries (for example the ones with bad formatted comments).

I'm new to regex and this task is taking me really too much time on my planning. Really need an help!

Here is what I should and shouldn't match:

```
YES: "product type1(0)"
YES: "product type2(923)"    
YES: "product type3(10)"
YES: "product type4(110.023) :here is a comment. It always starts with a semicolon"
YES: "product type1(14.4):comments can be just after product entry"
YES: "product type1(10.0)   : spaces are not relevant"
YES: "product type1(0000.01)   : this kind of entry is acceptable"

NO:  "product type1(asd)"
NO:  "product type1(12a3.02)" 
NO:  "product type2(0.)"
NO:  "product type2(0.123.123)"
NO:  "product type2(0...)"
NO:  "product type3(0.asd)"
NO:  "product type4(10)" comment doesn't start with a semicolon
```

Here is my attempt. I know I have to improve it with `(?ifthen|else)` patterns and lookaheads. My problems arise namely when I try to use conditional regex that embodies lookhaeds. A simply explanation is welcome.

```
^product (type1|type2|type3|type4)\(([0-9]+\.?[0-9]+)\)[ ]+;?
```

Thank you.

Comment: In .NET, you can also use `(?m)"(product type[1-4]\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\)(?(\s*:)\s*:[^"]*?)|\s*)"\s*(?=$|\p{Zl})` with a conditional expression (if you are interested, I will post as an answer). See http://goo.gl/gE7Dk0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following to match:

```
^"(product\stype[1234]\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\))\s*(:.*?)?"$
```

and replace the matches with `$1`

Explanation:

- `^"(product\s` start with quotes, open capture group, followed by `product`, followed by `space`
- `type[1234]` followed by `type` and any of four digits
- `\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?\))` followed by literal `(` and any number of digits, followed by zero or one occurance of decimal part (dot and digits), close capture group
- `\s*(:.*?)?"$` followed by extra space, followed by comments may or may not be `?`, followed by quotes and end of the string (nothing afterwords)

See [DEMO and more Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/rA2sV2/3)

Answer (score 0):

This regex works for me:

```
^product (type[1234])\((\d+(\.\d+)?)\)\s*(:.*)?$
```

The first capture group should have the type, and the second should have the diameter.

To break it down:

[start of line anchor][literal: "product "][literal: "type"][a 1, 2, 3, or a 4][literal open parenthesis][at least one digit][optionally a decimal point and at least one more digit][literal close parenthesis][any amount (including 0 characters) of whitespace][optionally a colon followed by anything][end of line anchor]

Answer (score 0):

My solution would be

```
^product type[1234]\((?<num>\d+(?:\.?\d+)?)\)\s*(?:$|:+)
```

which is similar to other solutions but selects the number in the braces into a named group "num"